# PIL saves large images as static

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, save

I'm using PIL (Python Imaging Library) to stitch together several hundred 512x512 images. The resulting image is about 300 MB. It works perfectly for results that are around 50 - 150 MB, but after some unknown border, they start becoming giant statics. They look like the following image.

[image: Static]

I've tried making sure I have over 300 MB in memory. I have about 4 GB free right now, and it's still having this problem. I think it is an issue with PIL. I'm guessing it isn't supposed to handle huge files.

Please help.

edit: img.show() actually shows the picture (in Preview, cause I have a Mac). It's compressed when it's shown, though, I think, because I can see the compression by comparing the smaller files and it says it's a .jpeg

Comment: Is 300MB the uncompressed size of the image, or the size of a PNG or JPG or something? (Errors crossing 2GB or 4GB would make a lot more sense than errors crossing 300MB… but it could also be something like crossing 64Kpix width.)

Comment: Also, which version of PIL (or Pillow) are you using? It's possible that you've hit a bug that's already been fixed…

Comment: Finally, are you sure the files are actually bad, and it's not just whatever you're using to view them? Because I just created a PNG whose dimensions are 2Mx60 (a bit over 300MB uncompressed, under 1MB compressed) and opened it in various programs on my Mac. Preview and Firefox both give me errors immediately; QuickLook shows it as a 0x0 image; Chrome spins for 3 minutes before showing a broken image tag; a simple CoreImage viewer shows it as the right size (or at least very wide) but solid black… Nothing showed it correctly.

Comment: And LibreOffice Draw finally finished opening it… I've got a very-wrong-shaped (much taller than wide… but the dimensions claim it's 0 pixels tall) weird set of red bands.

Comment: Finally found something that can handle it: ImageMagick. So, you can use that to crop, say, the rightmost 512x512 and then view that in another program and see if it's really static, or just your viewer. But then it's probably simpler to just test in PIL itself: reopen the giant file, crop the rightmost 512x512, and either save and view that, or just `getpixel` and check the values…

Answer (score 1):

It's quite possible that your actual problem is not with PIL, but with whatever you're using to display the image.

It's also possible that your problem is with PIL, and it's been fixed by Pillow 2.0, or it only happens on 32-bit, or whatever, but I couldn't reproduce it.

Anyway, here's my code to generate a 2Mx60 PNG file, which is over 300MB uncompressed (but under 1MB compressed), out of a bunch of copies of a 512x60 PNG:

```
>>> src = PIL.Image.open('strip-512x60.png')
>>> dst = PIL.Image.new('RGBA', (4096*512, 60))
>>> for i in range(4096):
...    dst.paste(src, (4096*i, 0))
>>> dst.save('strip-3Mx60.png')
```

I examined the file; it's got a valid PNG block structure and all the right info in the IHDR.

I can reopen it in PIL, and the pixels are clearly valid:

```
>>> dst = PIL.Image.open('strip-3Mx60.png')
>>> src.getpixel((0, 30))
(115, 67, 19)
>>> dst.getpixel((0, 30))
(115, 67, 19)
>>> dst.getpixel((4000*512, 30))
(115, 67, 19)
```

ImageMagick's command-line tools can also read the file perfectly well; cropping off the next-to-last 512x512 into a new file and opening it gave me the original image (or at least something close enough to pass a quick visual inspection).

However, almost any other program or high-level library I try to open it with either fails, or gives me garbage:

- QuickLook syslogs "ImageIO: PNG Invalid IHDR Data" then returns a 0x0 image.
- A trivial CoreImage test program syslogs "ImageIO: PNG Invalid IHDR Data" then returns a solid black image in what I'm guessing is a default size (somewhere around 600x600).
- Preview gives an error about invalid file type.
- Firefox gives an error about invalid image contents.
- Chrome and Safari display a broken image tag. It takes a few minutes.
- LibreOffice Draw gives me an image that's something like 600x64K, made up of bizarre bands of red, white, and black. It takes even longer than WebKit.
- A trivial .NET image viewer (running in Mono) spews out a ton of errors, and then displays traditional analog-TV-style static. It takes even longer than LibreOffice.

Presumably Apple's libraries (except WebKit) and Gecko are just doing some kind of sanity check, and deciding that any IHDR that claims to be 2M pixels wide is invalid, while everything else is trying to interpret the image and then overflowing some internal buffer before either aborting, or not noticing and just returning garbage.

Comment: Hahaha. Another thing I didn't mention was that img.show() shows the image. I'm guessing because it also compresses it a little. You can see the compression in the smaller images (it turns into a .jpeg).

Tell me if you find any way to open it, I guess.

Comment: @wufufufu: Well, that gives you an easy test to make sure it's actually `Image.save` that's to blame: save the image, reopen it, and show it.

Answer (score 0):

Just ran the same code on Windows. It worked. The actual image is corrupted when it's saved by Python on Mac, I'm pretty sure.

I was running Python 2.5 with PIL 1.1.7 on **both** Windows and Mac